# Why is my customtkinter Frame's width not working?

Tags: python, width, sidebar, init, customtkinter

Okay so I'm trying to make a Sidebar using customtkinter, but I can't set the width of the frame. Every other property that I'm defining in the `__init__` function works, but width and height don't.

My code for the class definition looks like this:

```
class Sidebar(customtkinter.CTkFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        customtkinter.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent, fg_color="black", bg_color="red", width=20, border_color="green", border_width=20)
        self.controller = controller
        
        heading = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Sidebar")
        heading.pack(side=customtkinter.TOP)
```

The result looks like this:
[ctkframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56qaE.png)

Everything works, except that is clearly more than twenty wide. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: how do you use it? Maybe problem is parent for this element. Maybe you should change width, height of parent. Or maybe you should add `margins` like `pack(padx=10, pady=10, ...)`. Layout manager `pack` always tries to automatically control widget's size and sometimes it make problem - it may need to put widget in other widget to use different `layout manager` like `grid` or `place`

Comment: better in question show `minimal working code` so we could run it and see how you use other elements in Window.